# Qt not working when my array reach a certain size

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

For testing purposes, I'm trying different sizes of arrays in Qt.

Here is the code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int const sizeArray = 519199;

int main()
{    
    string arr[sizeArray];

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++)
    {    
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    arr[499999] = "Test";
    cout << arr[499999] << endl;
}
```

When `sizeArray` is 519999, the program runs quickly and displays "Test". But when `sizeArray` is 519200 or more, the program takes longer to run (approx 5s) then finishes without displaying "Test".

Is this a memory limit by the OS or by Qt?

Comment: You are exceeding the size of your stack. This has nothing to do with Qt. Ways to fix: allocate on the heap instead (or, better, just use a `std::vector`), or increase your stack size (bad fix).

Answer (score 6):

When you write:

```
string arr[sizeArray];
```

You're creating an array of `std::string` type with size `sizeArray` on the stack. Don't create such big arrays on the stack, as you're going to fill it very quickly; and, you won't be able to do much in your program, as you keep all your local variables on the stack. Use dynamic arrays, such as [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`QVector`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html) instead.

Here's an example of `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> arr(sizeArray);
```

Also, don't use C-style arrays. If you want a stack-array that you know the size of, and that it won't be very large (i.e. *it shouldn't exhaust the stack*), use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead, like so:

```
const int size_of_the_array = 10;
std::array<std::string, size_of_the_array> arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably just getting a stack overflow at **string arr[sizeArray];**

The array is too big to fit in your program's stack address space.

If you allocate the array on the heap, then it should be fine, assuming your machine has enough memory.

```
string *arr = new string[sizeArray];
```

But remember that, once usage of **arr** is done, it will be required you to delete[] the array as below:

```
delete[] arr;
```

As previous answer, you can use vectors too, instead of using large array on Stack. To get better clarity you can check [here](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/what+is+heap+and+stack)

Answer (score 0):

Anything other than automatic storage for the data of the array will work fine, though - and that's what you should use instead:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

static constexpr int N = 1000000;
static constexpr size_t pageSize = 4096;

template <typename R> void fill(R &range) {
  std::generate(range.begin(), range.end(), [i = 0]() mutable {
     return QString::number(i++);
  });
  qDebug() << *std::prev(std::cend(range));
}

int main() {
  static QVector<QString> array1(N);
  QVector<QString> array2(N);
  QVarLengthArray<QString> array3(N);
  auto array4 = std::make_unique<std::array<QString, N>>();//(new std::array<QString, N>);

  static_assert(sizeof(array1) < pageSize);
  static_assert(sizeof(array2) < pageSize);
  static_assert(sizeof(array3) < pageSize);
  static_assert(sizeof(array4) < pageSize);
  fill(array1);
  fill(array2);
  fill(array3);
  fill(*array4);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

did you mean that it’s ok when the size is 519199 and not 519999?

anyway to check if it’s limit of the stack try to do it with new.

string *arr = new string[sizeArray]